# Change Actionbar Overflow Menu Icon Between Portrait and Landscape

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

My app has a custom split action bar theme (yes, I'm using AcionBar Sherlock) where the top part is a dark colour, and the bottom part is a light colour. The app is set up to detect device orientation and remove the split actiobar when in landscape mode (just display the top actionbar). In some activities, I have an overflow menu indicated by the three vertical dots. I would like to set the overflow menu icon to a dark drawable when in portrait mode, and then a light drawable in landscape mode. Is there a way to change the overflow menu icon from the activity class?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/actionbarsherlock/vdbUXY-fqIw Then possibly mess around with the `port` and `land` qualifiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a custom style.
In this style you need to define:

```
<item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/customoverflow</item>
```

Something like this:

```
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
     <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
   </style>
   <style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_action_bTutton_overflow</item>
   </style>
```

You can define a styles.xml in values-land and a different styles.xml in values-port.

Comment: This is correct. Be VERY careful about changing this icon, however. It is meant to be recognized as a global icon that performs no direct action so changing it might make your users more hesitant to click it. The only valid use cases I've seen have been to adjust the color of the icon for different backgrounds.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm attempting to do, Adjust the colour of the icon depending on the background. Thanks for the help